# Cannot create container for service mysql: not a directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm new to docker and I get a strange error when building my first containers. I'm using WSL2 if that matters.

Here is the part that's causing it :

```
  # MySQL Service
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: usr_data
    volumes:
      - ./.docker/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      # - ./.docker/mysql/ohmy.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/my.cnf
      - ./.docker/test/test.txt:/tmp/test/test.txt
      - mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      test: mysqladmin ping -h 127.0.0.1 -u root --password=MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      interval: 5s
      retries: 10
```

Both files `my.cnf` and `ohmy.cnf` exist and have the same content.

When I use `docker-compose up -d` I get the error :

```
ERROR: for mysql  Cannot create container for service mysql: not a directory
```

When I uncomment the `ohmy.cnf` line and comment the `my.cnf` line I get no errors and it builds just fine. It also works great with the little `test.txt` I made.

I fail to see the difference between the two, and while it may work with my little workaround, I'd like to understand what is causing the error in the first place.

Thank you for your time.

Edit :
Here's my ./.docker

```
./.docker
├── mysql
│   ├── db
│   │   └── db.sql
│   ├── my.cnf
│   └── ohmy.cnf
├── nginx
│   └── conf.d
│       └── php.conf
├── php
│   └── Dockerfile
└── test
    └── test.txt

6 directories, 6 files
```

Comment: Can you try  changing the folder name from `.docker` to `docker` ?

Comment: Renaming from `docker` to `.docker` solved error `Cannot create container for service : not a directory` for me, but I can't understand why :-(

Comment: Encountered this problem on `wsl2`, switch to `windows-terminal` `PowerShell` then everything works fine. I guess this is a problem caused by docker.

Comment: as @circulosmeos, my file was also inside a folder named *docker*, so giving it a different name solved the same issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

In WSL 2 I updated docker compose to use $PWD instead of a relative path for volumes:

```
volumes:
  - $PWD/logs:/var/log/docker:delegated
```

Comment: This was my issue as well. Updated to 
wsl --version
WSL version: 0.50.2.0
Kernel version: 5.10.74.3
WSLg version: 1.0.29
Windows version: 10.0.22000.318

Answer (score 2):

Delete the volumes from `/var/lib/docker/volumes/[your-volumes]`. Run the below commands

1. `docker volume prune`
   Remove all unused local volumes. Unused local volumes are those which are not referenced by any containers.
2. `docker system prune`
   Remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unreferenced), and optionally, volumes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

`docker volume prune` did nothing.
`docker system prune` deleted a whole lot of things but i still get the exact same error.

Answer (score 0):

restarting my laptop helped in my special case, the other commands did not

Comment: Maybe the other commands worked but only *after* the reboot? Or does the reboot magically solve things if no other commands are made? Please elaborate. Thanks!